# Win32 PKCS#7 Low Level Message Functions to use specific content

Tags: winapi, cryptography, pkcs#7

When creating a PKCS#7 signed message with Win32 low level functions like [CryptMsgOpenToEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptmsgopentoencode) and [CryptMsgUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptmsgupdate), the resulting message is a message with OID 1.2.840.113549.1.7.2 signedData (PKCS #7), which contains a sequence with OID  1.2.840.113549.1.7.1 data (PKCS #7).

Can I use the low level message functions to change this latter OID? For example, Authenticode uses OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.4 spcIndirectDataContext (Microsoft code signing).

I saw CryptMsgOpenToEncode CMSG_BARE_CONTENT_FLAG flag, but I'm not sure if this is what I want or how to use it.

Comment: The [`CryptMsgOpenToEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptmsgopentoencode) function support open the cryptographic message with `SPC_INDIRECT_DATA_OBJID` (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.4). Why do you want to change latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (inner) content type of the message is the 5th parameter to `CryptMsgOpenToEncode` (`pszInnerContentObjID`).

It should accept any ASCII dotted decimal OID value as input, including the predefined value for the OID you mentioned (`SPC_INDIRECT_DATA_OBJID` / `"1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.1.4"`).

Comment: Thanks for that. I still have a weird problem, while the encoded message is passed correctly to CryptMsgUpdate, the resulting signature doesn't have it entirely inside. Duh - I guess I need to remove the DETACHED flag.